# Are simple animal snares and traps a form of automation? Of computation?

Tags: history, automation, computation

I'm trying to understand the relationship of humans and automation, historically and culturally.

I ask because the [waterclock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automation#Early_history) is generally considered the [earliest form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_clock) of automation, but snares and deadfall traps constitute simple switch [mechanisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanism_(engineering)).

*(They are single use without human-powered reset, but seem to qualify as machines. The bent sapling that powers the snare is referred to as the [engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=engine%20definition), which is "a machine with moving parts that converts power into motion.")*

If snares and traps are a form of automation, automation has been with us longer, potentially, than civilization.

- Are simple animal traps a form of automation or computation?

---

[image: simple snare for trapping small animals]

<sub>[How to make a simple snare (the Ready Store)](https://www.thereadystore.com/diy/6167/how-to-make-a-simple-snare/)</sub>

[image: Paiute Deadfall Trap]
<sub>[Paiute Deadfall Trap (Homestead Telegraph)](https://homesteadtelegraph.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/paiute-deadfall-trap/)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

- **Absolutely these traps and snares are a form of automation.**

They take a task--harvesting small animals--which was traditionally done by hunting them, and make the process automatic.  The mechanism requires a human to set up, but its function is automatic.  This is to say that the mechanism operates without human involvement.

- **Absolutely this is a form of computation.**

As DuttaA observed, these machines utilize a simple "IF/THEN" statement.  In the case of the snare:

> IF the hook is displaced from the base, THEN the sapling straightens

These simple machines will also return True or False:

> TRUE: The trap catches an animal 
>   FALSE: The trap is sprung but empty

The small animals are the input and, potentially, the output, depending on whether the mechanism returns "true".

<sub>*(The use of "true" has historically included phrases such as "their aim was true" in the sense of shooting an arrow or throwing a spear.)*</sub>